# What is the diffences between this two functions run in ReactJs's render() ?

Tags: reactjs

In my render() function , I want to run a function like this:

```
<a onClick={handleClickEdit(record.productId)}>Edit</a>
```

The function handleClickEdit(id) will be executed when component render , this is not what I want. I want to run  handleClickEdit(id) when I click the Edit label.
So , I tried a lot times, I found below style is worked well :

```
<a onClick={() =>handleClickEdit(record.productId)}>Edit</a>
```

What is the diffences between these code ? Plases help ,thanks a lot .

Answer (score 3):

`onClick` is a function that will be called whenever the component is clicked. The value assigned to it must be a function.

The expression `() => myFunction(arg)` wraps `myFunction` in an anonymous function; it is equivalent to:

```
function(){ return myFunction(arg); }
```

When the anonymous function is executed, `myFunction` is called with `arg` as an argument. Assigning the anonymous function to `onClick` means that `myFunction(arg)` will execute whenever the component is clicked. The value returned by `myFunction` is irrelevant. This is what happens in the second (working) code snippet.

In the first code snippet, `myFunction(arg)` is assigned directly to `onClick`. But `myFunction(arg)` is not a function — it is a function *invocation*; `myFunction` is executed immediately with `arg` as an argument, and the **returned value** gets assigned to `onClick`. The returned value may not even be a function!

If you don't want to use the arrow notation / explicit wrapper-function, you could use:

```
onClick={ myFunction.bind(null, arg) }
```

You can read more about `Function.prototype.bind` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind); it returns a new function with `arg` bound as the first argument. The first argument passed to `bind` will be bound to the `this` keyword during function execution.

Comment: Very helpful ! Thank you very much !  I learn a lot of new knowledge according of your answer ! Thanks again .